# How to change mysqldump USE DATABASE

Tags: mysql, mariadb, backup

Is there a way to remove/change the `USE databasename` from the `.sql` file generated with `mySqlDump`?

I'm useing the following commandline

```sh
bin/mysqldump.exe -uName -pPass --single-transaction --routines --triggers --host host_test.com  --databases testreporting > backups/testreporting.sql
```

The part I want changed is the start

```
--
-- Current Database: `testreporting`
--

CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `testreporting` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;

USE `testreporting`;
```

Comment: @basha04 will try :) I will write soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `--databases`
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_databases

> --databases, -B Dump several databases. Normally, mysqldump treats the first name argument on the command line as a database name and
> following names as table names. With this option, it treats all name
> arguments as database names. CREATE DATABASE and USE statements are
> included in the output before each new database. This option may be
> used to dump the performance_schema database, which normally is not
> dumped even with the --all-databases option. (Also use the
> --skip-lock-tables option.) Note See the --add-drop-database description for information about an incompatibility of that option
> with --databases.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, do you think the mysqldump looks good enough for a 5GB database? :) I'm pretty new to useing it

Comment: 5gb is very small database. If you have  `MyIsam` tables you should add `--lock-tables=false` is the same as `--single-transaction` that is used for Innodb tables. I think you are ok

Comment: It's `Innodb` so this should be fine then :)

Comment: Do `MySql.exe` on importing have a max `.sql` file size it can import? (or is it the size of the database which is the limit?)

Comment: As far as I know it does not.

Comment: Do you know why when i look at the MySQL Workbench summary table list for the Original_table and compare it with Original_table_copy, that some of the tables aren't the same? (it looks like) but when I test it they have the same content? I will post a question about it if you dont know it :)

Comment: Made a post about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69044490/mysql-import-table-not-the-same-size-as-the-one-exported-from

Comment: @MadsSanderHøgstrup i saw that another have answered in the comments, and i hope you get the idea. To be sure make a select `count(*)` for the same tables in both the db.